# Notation for Conditional PMF Conditioned on Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I'm trying to define a simple conditional PMF,

$$
\begin{equation} 
p_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y) = \Pr(X = x \mid Y = y) = \frac{\Pr(X=x\, \cap\, Y=y)}{\Pr(Y = y)}.
\end{equation}
$$

The problem is that sometimes I only know a distribution for $Y$ so something like

$$p_{X\mid Y\sim D}(x\mid d) = \Pr(X = x \mid Y\sim d).$$

(I made up the above notation to convey my idea. I realize it is probably completely wrong)

Is there a simple way to express this idea in formal writing? I'd like to just put $d$ in for $y$ but $\Pr(X = x \mid Y = d)$ seems like an abuse of notation. Do I have to define two separate PMF's? Also, extending my outcome space $\Omega$ to include distributions $D$ over $Y$ seems wrong too, so I don't want to make $d$ an event...

Comment: If you know the distribution of $Y$ then you ought to have the CDF and hence the PMF (in principle) so the usual definition of conditional PMF works provided the conditioning event has non-zero chance. The sample space isn’t extended, its shrunk by the conditioning event. Otherwise it is not clear to me what your question is really getting at. Perhaps you have specific examples in mind to clarify?

Comment: @NapD.Lover I do know the CDF, and it is a valid PMF (that is that it sums to one and is a non-negative measure on a sigma-algebra). I can do calculations with it no problem. I'm simply struggling with the correct notation for a paper. That is, sometimes the conditioning event is $Y$ = y, and sometimes the conditioning event is $Y \sim{} d$. What's the correct notation to use when your conditioning event is itself a probability distribution...

Comment: It just occurred to me, maybe a question about notation isn't appropriate for this StackExchange?

Comment: Once the probability law $\mathrm{Pr}$ and the random variables $X, Y:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ are fixed, then there is no way you can change the distribution of $Y$, and so, it seems meaningless to treat the distribution $D$ of $Y$ as a variable. To change $D$, you need to change the ambient probability law $\mathrm{Pr}$ itself. (Actually, this kind of consideration frequently occurs in the theory of Markov chains.) Or, is your $Y$ actually a probability-measure-valued random variable, a.k.a. random probability measure? In any cases, supplying some more context would be appreciated.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thanks for the comment. To your first point, that's why I talked above about extending my event space in the question, that is add an event $Z$ so that when $Z$ occurs $Y\sim{}D$. And no, $Y$ isn't a random function, it's an event. From your comment it sounds like I might simply need to define two CDF's. (and yeah, I'm working with Markov chains where the $Y$ is actually the initial state and $X$ are paths in the chain. So sometimes I start at a fixed state and sometimes there's a distribution of states. I was trying to stay out of the weeds so didn't mention Markov chains.)

Comment: In such case, the law of the Markov chain subject to the initial distribution $\mu$ is often written as $\mathbb{P}^{\mu}$ (or as one of its typography variants). In other words, $\mathbb{P}^{\mu}$ is the probability law under which $X_0 \sim \mu$. It is customary to simply write $\mathbb{P}^x$ (as opposed to $\mathbb{P}^{\delta_x}$) for the law of $X$ subject to the initial condition $\mathbb{P}^x(X_0 = x) = 1$, and of course we have $$\mathbb{P}^{\mu}(\cdot) = \int_{\mathcal{S}}\mathbb{P}^x(\cdot)\,\mu(\mathrm{d}x).$$